# Why are conformal mappings necessarily 1 to 1?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Say, by the Riemann Mapping Theorem, there exists a biholomorphic, conformal mapping from the upper half plane to the (open) unit disk (since the UHP is simply connected and is not the entire complex plane.)

This mapping, call it $f(z)$, is intuitively an onto-mapping, since we can shrink the points in the UHP by suitable scaling to fit into the unit disk in the $w$-plane.

But why would such a mapping necessarily be one-to-one?

The UHP is so much bigger than the unit disk that...shouldn't we run into the situation were $z_1 \ne z_2$, but $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$?

Thanks,

Edit: I'm wondering whether the condition $f'$ not zero (non-vanishing derivative) makes the mapping one-to-one, but I am doubtful; I think the non-vanishing derivative only makes the mapping locally invertible, by the inverse function theorem.  But I guess we can use this argument for all of the UHP, and conclude the mapping from the UHP to the unit disk is invertible, one-to-one, and onto.  Am I close?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=e^x$. It is locally conformal, yet globally, $f(x)=f(x+2\pi i)$, so it is not injective (and $f'(x)$ is never $0$).

Comment: QUOTE This mapping, call it $f(z)$, is intuitively an onto-mapping, since we can shrink the points in the UHP by suitable scaling to fit into the unit disk in the $w$-plane. END QUOTE ${}\qquad{}$ I don't see how this makes sense.  If you mean it's _onto the disk_, then showing that the image of the function is entirely within the disk doesn't do that. And how could a rescaling in the $z$-plane rather than the $w$-plane make it fit into the disk? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks for the example to consider, @RobJohn.

Comment: Good points, @Michael Hardy.  hmmm...

Comment: Hi @robjohn, then what good is the assumption of f(z) having non-vanishing derivative?  Is it a necessary but insufficient condition for injectivity of f?  It guarantees the injectivity of f, locally, I think (since f is never constant, locally.)

Comment: @LebronJames: The injectivity is an added constraint. It is not given by the non-vanishing derivative. The non-vanishing derivative ensures that angles are preserved, thus giving the conformality (local preservation of shape).

Comment: Thanks @robjohn.  Can I ask one more question?  As I mentioned below to Andreas Blass's answer, I am able to show that z-i/z+i is one-to-one, by a simple contradiction proof.  Also, with the standard symmetry arguments, I know that the UHP maps to the inside of the unit disk in the w-plane, while the LHP maps to the outside.  But even though I am able to see the injectivity of f, algebraically, on paper, I still find it hard to believe, like many results in complex analysis.  Do you have a suggestion on how I can think of why the mapping is one-to-one, besides an algebraic proof?  Thanks,

Comment: ... is it the scaling by the factor 1/z+i ?

Comment: @LebronJames: the only way to show injectivity of $f$ is to assume $f(z)=f(w)$ and show that $z=w$ (i.e. algebraically).  Differentiability is a local property, whereas injectivity is a global property.  This is why a non-vanishing derivative does not imply injectivity.

Comment: @LebronJames: Any conformal map is locally a translation composed with a scaling and a rotation. This is because locally, a conformal map is given by $$f(z)=\color{#00A000}{f(w)+}\color{#C00000}{f'(w)}(z\color{#00A000}{-w})$$ where the green parts contribute to the translation and the red parts to the rotation and scaling. $|f'(w)|$ is the scaling and $\arg(f'(w))$ is the rotation.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for the help, @robjohn.  Have a great night.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't bijectivity part of the definition of "biholomorphic"?  In the particular situation you described, mapping the upper half-plane to the unit disk, instead of invoking the Riemann mapping theorem, you might as well look at a specific such mapping, say 
$$ z\mapsto\frac{z-i}{z+i},$$
check by calculation that it's one-to-one, and draw some pictures to see how this "compression" of the half-plane into the disk works.

Comment: Hi, @AndreasBlass, I was able to write a simple proof by contradiction to show that this mapping is indeed one-to-one.  And yes, one-to-one and onto, together with non-vanishing derivative are necessary but not sufficient conditions to imply that the mapping is biholomorphic and conformal, I think.  Hmm...even though I am now able to show the one-to-one condition, it seems hard to believe, conceptually.  How can I best think of this "compression" action?

Comment: Actually, sorry, I think f(z) one-to-one and onto, with non-vanishing derivative, suitably restricted, is a conformal mapping.

Comment: Well, both the unit disk and the upper half-plane have the same cardinality, so there's no problem there. The upper half-plane has infinite area, while the unit disk has finite area; but biholomorphic functions don't have to preserve area, so that's not a problem, either. If you're familiar with an order-preserving bijection between the open interval $(0,1)$ and the entire real line, this biholomorphic function acts much the same way.

Answer (score 2):

While it was shown by explicit example that a particular conformal mapping from the upper half plane to the unit disk is one-to-one, the more general question of "why conformal mappings are one-to-one" was not addressed in detail. It was mentioned in a comment that conformal mappings are "locally linear", heuristically implying that they are locally one-to-one. While this may be good intuition to keep in mind, it is not precise. In the edit of the question, it is stated that "I think the non-vanishing derivative only makes the mapping locally invertible". Indeed: consider the function $z \mapsto z^2$ restricted to the annulus $A = \{ z : 1 < |z| < 2 \}$. On $A$, this mapping is conformal, but not one-to-one. Let us prove the following:

If $f$ is conformal in an open set $G$, then for each $a \in G$ there exists an $r > 0$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $D(a;r)$ is one-to-one.
[$D(a;r)$ represents the open disk centered at $a$ of radius $r$.]

Take $a \in G$ arbitrarily and find $R > 0$ such that 1) $\bar{D}(a;R) \subset G$ and 2) $f(z) - f(a)$ is never zero in the set $\bar{D}(a;R) \backslash \{ a \}$. We must be allowed point 2) by the identity theorem: if we could not find any such $R$ we would be able to construct a sequence $\{ z_n \}$, converging to $a \in G$, on which $f-f(a)$ vanishes. This would imply $f=f(a)$ in a neighborhood of $a$, in turn implying $f'(a) = 0$, which is not allowed by the conformality of $f$. In the following we'll use the result ([Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem)):

Let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic inside and on a contour $\gamma$ and suppose that $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$ on $\gamma$. Then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeroes inside $\gamma$.

With this in mind, define $m = \inf \{ |f(z)-f(a)| : z \in C(a;R) \} > 0$, where $C(a;R)$ represents the circle of radius $R$ around $a$. Rouché's theorem now implies that for any $w \in D(f(a);m)$, the functions $f(z)-f(a)$ and $f(z)-w$ have the same amount of zeroes in the domain $D(a;R)$, that is, precisely one. Finally, by continuity of $f$ at $a$, we can always find an $r > 0$ with $r < R$ such that $f(D(a;r)) \subset D(f(a);m)$. Then it is not hard to see that $f$ restricted to $D(a;r)$ is one-to-one.

NOTE: this proof is an exercise, 16.5, in Priestley's book [Introduction to Complex Analysis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Complex_Analysis.html?id=qT8kAwAAQBAJ&hl=en). All the elements that went into the above proof are heavily inspired by the preceding chapters of the book.